# WooCommerce Hook ( woocommerce_order_status_changed ) cant run javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, firebase, hook-woocommerce

i tried to run javascript in this hook, but it cant work. I am pretty sure that this hook is triggered as i can perform php insert to the database and write to debug_log. I would like to ask does it have the solution to solve it ?

function.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'your_function', 10, 3 ); 
function your_function( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status ){ 

    // This doesnt work

    // Enqueued script with localized data.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'order_status_changed_1', 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.3.0/firebase-app.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'order_status_changed_2', 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.3.0/firebase-auth.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'order_status_changed_3', 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.3.0/firebase-firestore.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'order_status_changed_4', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/scripts_v1.js' );

    // Localize the script with new data
    $data = array(
        'order_number' => $order_id,
        'order_status' => $new_status,
        'action' => 'update_order_status'
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'order_status_changed_4', 'data', $data );

    // This work (Below code)

    global $wpdb;
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO `test`(`order_id`, `status`) VALUES (%s,%s)",$order_id,$new_status);
    $wpdb->query($sql);

    error_log("Trigger");
}
```

scripts_v1.js

```
var action = data.action;
if(action == "update_order_status" ){

    console.log("here");

    db.collection("orders").doc(data.order_number).update({
        orderStatus : data.order_status
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log("Document successfully updated!");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        // The document probably doesn't exist.
        console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hook might be triggered but that's not the way to enqueue scripts. Scripts are added by:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'your_function')
function your_function(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'order_status_changed_1','https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.3.0/firebase-app.js');
}
```

That means your JS is not added to the page (check your Network tab in developer tools).

You could add the scripts in a different way by outputting the script directly. Or you conditionally load your scripts on the page that is loaded after the order status is changed.

That means your use the enqueue action as usual. But you add a condition for enqueuing the script:

```
if(is_page('order-status-changed'){
// wp_enqueue_script
}
```

Maybe you can give some more info surrounding the order change status, and what your objective is?

Comment: The code above i had tried in another hook, and its work. I think it might be related to the wp-admin? As my objective is to update the order status to firebase , when admin manually update the order status at the dashboard. I tried your way, it works at the front, but when come to the dashboard, any javascript didnt even load.

Comment: ah sorry, I didn't know it was intended for the wp-admin.
wp_enqueue_scripts need to become admin_enqueue_scripts then. I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope help:

```
if(data.action == "update_order_status" ){ <-- edit

    console.log("here");

    db.collection("orders").doc(data.order_number).update({
        orderStatus : data.order_status
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log("Document successfully updated!");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        // The document probably doesn't exist.
        console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, i forget to put the variable that i already declared. Anyways, thanks. =)